# jquery code to hide option value does not work in IE10

Tags: jquery

I am working with a calculator in my drupal website. In my calculator, there is a dropdown menu where the choices has a specific value. 
example:
option      corresponding value
norm        131
tag         132
bill        133
exchange    134

after selecting an option, the calculator will calculate the value and display it on screen.
an Add image is provided to add another set of calculator for other calculations.
What I want to do is when the value 133 was already chosen on the pervious calculator, it will not appear on the drop down menu of the next calculator and so on.

I have a hardcoded jquery function in my drupal website, that clones my calculator. I managed to hide the option with value 133 when chosen and it works fine and does not show itself on the next calculator. however, this is only working on firefox but not in IE10. Please help. here are my codes

```
$('.add_category').live('click', function(e){
   if(($('.category_box:last .calc_cat option').length - 1) == $('.category_box').length)
   {
      //return false;
   }
   last_cat_array.push(tid);
   //alert(last_cat_array); 
   if(jQuery.inArray('133',last_cat_array) == -1){
      // the element is not in the array
      obj_clone = $('.category_box:last').clone();
      $('.category_box:last').after(obj_clone);
      $('.category_box:last').find('.calc_cat_sub_container').css({ visibility : 'hidden'});
      $('.category_box:last').find('.calc_cat_sub').html('<option value="">--</option>');
      $('.category_box:last').find('.amount_label').text('Amount');
      obj_clone.find('.calc_cat').val(0);
      obj_clone.find('.amount').val('');
      obj_clone.find('.points').val('');
      obj_clone.find('.show_details').hide();
   }
   else
   { //the element is in the array
      obj_clone = $('.category_box:last').clone();
      $('.category_box:last').after(obj_clone);
      $('.category_box:last').find('.calc_cat_sub_container').css({ visibility : 'hidden'});
      $('.calc_cat').children("option[value='133']").css('display','none'); 
      $('.category_box:last').find('.calc_cat_sub').html('<option value="">--</option>');
      $('.category_box:last').find('.amount_label').text('Amount');
      obj_clone.find('.calc_cat').val(0);
      obj_clone.find('.amount').val('');
      obj_clone.find('.points').val('');
      obj_clone.find('.show_details').hide();
   };
});
```

Thank you guys

Comment: check the console in IE10s Developer Tools. my suspicion is that there will be an obj_clone is undefined error. this is because IE doesnt like variables to be declared without the var keyword

Comment: only work in Firefox, but in IE10. How about IE9, Chrome and Safari? Any error in F12 Developer Tools?

Comment: This has been the same in all versions of IE...very little support for hide or events on `<option>` tag and therefore not a good approach

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of support in IE, for `display:none` which has always been the case going back years is best to rebuild the options ( can also do a simple `remove()`-see note at bottom). Also in IE you can't register click handlers on `<option>` tag

Example:

HTML

```
<select id="select-1">
   <option value="1">One</option >
   <option value="2">Two</option >
</select>

<select id="select-2">
   <option value="1">One</option >
   <option value="2">Two</option >
</select>
```

JS

```
/* first store a complete set of clones*/
var select2Options= $('#select-2 option').clone();

$('#select-1').change(function(){
   var val=$(this).val();
   /* create new set filtering out value selected in #select-1*/
   var options= select2Options.clone().filter(function(){
       return this.value != val;
   });
   $('#select-2').html( options);

});
```

This is the simplest case for select that is not set as `multiple` and assumes no selected options in second select.

You can also just remove an `<option>` if that suits the application. ABove will allow user multiple changes to the first `<select>`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bGXts/)**</kbd>